# Picking an optimal initial congestion window size (high bw, high latency and short bursts)?

Tags: computer-networks, network-flow, communication-protocols

What is a known strategy to approach a situation where short bursts of data are being sent very often over a high bandwidth, high latency cable? I am aware of cubic but even that does not utilize a 10GBps cable in a short burst scenario.

Lets say I have a distributed network where a single computer is sending tasks to many other computers. The computers then respond with a short answer 50-100KB. We need to receive these answers as quickly as possible.

What are the consideration and do we determine the optimal initial congestion window size?

Assumptions:

1. Using TCP Cubic.
2. Bursts are arrive with a Poisson distribution.
3. Goal is to get the data as quickly as possible.
4. Two scenarios, limited or vast buffer size.

Comment: The TCP parameters are for each connection, set when it is created.

Comment: Yes, so if I want to maximize performance, do I draw statistics and set TCP connection attributes accordingly? I wish to figure what would be a reasonable set of values for the initial window size in a specific setup.